# Core 3.1 - Binding some properties from Body and some others from Header

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following model:

```
public class Network {
    public string Network { get; set; }
    public string Cidr { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

And the following endpoint:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<Network>> PostNetwork(Network network)
{
    ...
}
```

And would like to know if it's possible to bind `Network` and `Cidr` with values from my post `Body`, and the `TenantId` with the value from a specific header.

I don't wan't to put `entity.TenantId = HttpContext.Request.Headers["TenantId"];` all over my controllers endpoint because this pattern is necessary to several entities/endpoints.

I've tried to create a custom middle-ware to edit my Body content, but the changes wasn't reflected in my controller. Also tried to use a custom DataBinder but without success.

Comment: What went wrong with the custom data binder, that should be the way to do it

Comment: Hey George, do you have any example that would do something similar? Following the documentation wasn't really clear for me how it should be implemented.

Comment: Sure, I'll post it as an answer, it _should_ work but might not be the best practise or what not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you'll need to create a custom model binder and add an attribute to your class.

The model binder will inherit from `IModelBinder` and assuming your data is JSON

```
public class NetworkModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        Network model;

        string bodyAsText = await new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Network>(bodyAsText);
        model.TenantId = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["TenantId"];
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
    }
}
```

Then add the `ModelBinder` attribute to the class to tell it to use that model binder

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(NetworkModelBinder))]
public class Network
{
    public string Network { get; set; }
    public string Cidr { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an issue with the `Network` property on the class saying "Member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type" other than that, this compiles (for core 2.1, but hopefully it's the same in 3.x), please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I've changed the model in my question just to make it simpler and haven't noticed the name conflict. And yes, it worked, and it's way more cleaner than what I was doing, really appreciate it. :) Just changed a bit to make it generic and adapt to my model. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My task was to fill the property of each object which implements the specific interface from a header. I resolved it by decorating the default ModelBinderFactory.

```
public sealed class CustomModelBinderFactory : ModelBinderFactory, IModelBinderFactory
{
    public CustomModelBinderFactory(
        IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
        IOptions<MvcOptions> options,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(metadataProvider, options, serviceProvider)
    {
    }

    public new IModelBinder CreateBinder(ModelBinderFactoryContext context)
    {
        var binder = base.CreateBinder(context);

        return new NodeIdBinder(binder);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Wrapper on the resolved by <see cref="ModelBinderFactory"/> binder.
    /// </summary>
    private sealed class NodeIdBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        private readonly IModelBinder _originalBinder;
               
        public NodeIdBinder(IModelBinder originalBinder)
        {
            _originalBinder = originalBinder;
        }
        
        public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            await _originalBinder.BindModelAsync(bindingContext);

            if (bindingContext.Result.Model is IQueryWithNode model)
            {
                var nodeId = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Node"];
                model.NodeId = nodeId;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The interface example

```
public interface IQueryWithNode
{
    public string NodeId { get; set; }
}
```

This factory should be added to a container. I didn't find an official way to do it, so I used

```
services.AddSingleton<IModelBinderFactory, CustomModelBinderFactory>();
```

Now any request which consumes the object that implements this interface will have the *NodeId* property filled.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this solution because I feel it's simpler & easier to read and maintain.

That said...
This should work 95% of the time.
However, truly "Complex Objects" may need their own JSON Deserializer class.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Save([ModelBinder(typeof(EmployeeModelBinder))] Employee entity)
{
    // Do awesome stuff here
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Find([ModelBinder(typeof(EmployeeModelBinder))] EmployeeFilter filter)
{
    // Do awesome stuff here
}

public class EmployeeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        var key = bindingContext.ModelName;
        var result = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key);

        // Exists?
        if (result.Length == 0)
            return Task.CompletedTask;

        // Deserialize
        var json = result.ToString();
        switch (key)
        {
            case "entity":
                var entity = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Employee>(json);
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(entity);
                break;
                
            case "filter":
                var filter = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeFilter>(json);
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(filter);
                break;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```